# What software can I use to edit interlinked HTML files without reading source code?

Tags: html, html-editor, wysiwyg, documentation-generator

My company has inherited a large user guide that is comprised of a master `.htm` that works as a table of contents and has hyperlinks to child `.htm` files that are either a leaf(containing the desired information) or a node with a secondary table.  We've been hired to do some formatting changes and add code examples, but beyond hitting `F12` and hunting for the appropriate space (~500 times) to add my own div I'm unsure how I should proceed.

Is there software I can use to edit these documents, or can anyone suggest the program that was probably used to make this browser-based guide to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web browser that also can be used as a what-you-see-is-what-you-get HTML editor.

The only one I know and have used is a very old program called Amaya.

It lets you browse the HTML files, click on links, and when you see something you want to fix, just start typing and it inserts your text, images, etc.

It is free and open source.

The interface probably feels very old nowadays, but it fits your purpose.

[image]